# wrong status line: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I am getting a weird error when i make http request.

The request code is like this;

```
purchase_xml = Transaction.yo_xml(api_username,api_password,@total, account, merchant_reference)
            uri = URI.parse(url)
            http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
            request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
            request.body = purchase_xml
            response = http.request(request)
            result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```

Where the yo_xml looks like this;

```
def self.yo_xml(api_username, api_password,amount, account, transaction_id)
        xml = "<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?><AutoCreate><Request><APIUsername>#{api_username}</APIUsername>
                <APIPassword>#{api_password}</APIPassword><Method>acdepositfunds</Method><Amount>#{amount}</Amount>
                <Account>#{account}</Account><Narrative>Purchase of SMS</Narrative><InternalReference>#{transaction_id}</InternalReference>
                <ExternalReference>#{transaction_id}</ExternalReference><ProviderReferenceText>Thank you for using Skyline SMS</ProviderReferenceText>
                </Request></AutoCreate>"
        return xml
    end
```

I am getting this error;

```
Net::HTTPBadResponse
wrong status line: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">"
```

raised o this line

```
response = http.request(request)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have gotten an error similar to this before trying to access a resource over https. You didn't mention if that was the case, but if so setting `http.use_ssl = true` before the `post` might fix it.

Answer (score 4):

This is how i got it to work

```
purchase_xml = Transaction.yo_xml(api_username,api_password,@total, account, merchant_reference)
            uri = URI.parse(url)
            http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
            request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
            request.body = purchase_xml
            http.use_ssl = true
            http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
            response = http.request(request)
            result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```